# How to make HTTP post request with specific body? And how to access token from the server to allow me to login?

Tags: authentication, swift3, http-post

I'm having a scenario like :

1) I want to create Http POST request and for this I'm having the data, please see this image:

[image]

2) As you can see in the above image, I have to create post a request with the mentioned body and also I'm getting response named: token. How to create post request and fetch this token response?.

3) That token response will allow me to login into myapp.

I'm newbie to this scenario. I have tried some code by my own but still getting confuse in how to combine my app delegate code with this POST Request Code.

**Code**

```
 @IBAction func signinaction(_ sender: Any) {

    self.username.resignFirstResponder()
    self.password.resignFirstResponder()

    if (self.username.text == "" || self.password.text == "") {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Login failed",
                                          message: "Wrong username or password." as String, preferredStyle:.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again!", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertView.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    // Check if the user entered an email
    if let actualUsername = self.username.text {

        // Check if the user entered a password
        if let actualPassword = self.password.text {

            // Build the body message to request the token to the web app
            self.bodyStr = "username=8870417698&password=1234&grant_type=password" + actualUsername + "&password=" + actualPassword

            // Setup the request
            let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://ezschoolportalapi.azurewebsites.net/token")!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.httpBody = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if  data?.count != 0
 {

                    do {

                                                   let tokenDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                        print(tokenDictionary)
                        // Get the token
                        let token:String = tokenDictionary["access_token"] as! String

                        // Keep record of the token

                        let userdefaults = UserDefaults()

                        let saveToken = userdefaults.set(token, forKey: "access_token")
                        userdefaults.synchronize()


                        // Dismiss login view and go to the home view controller
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }


                    }
                    catch {
                        // Wrong credentials
                        // Reset the text fields
                        self.username.text = ""
                        self.password.text = ""

                        // Setup the alert
                        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Login failed",
                                                          message: "Wrong username or password." as String, preferredStyle:.alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again!", style:.default, handler: nil)
                        alertView.addAction(okAction)
                        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

**Question is how to combine this code with my above code :**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate  appDelegate.gotoMainvc()
```

if I use directly this code then in any of the case I'm able to switch over to my home screen it doesn't matter whether m using this POST Request code or not. Please Help.

Comment: What is not working with current code ?

Comment: code is working fine but it should be allow me to login after fetching the token and then enter the username & password.

Comment: Are you getting any response with your current code or getting any error when you run this code

Comment: yes m getting response of that access token bt it's not allow me to login.see I've updated my question with response

Comment: What do you mean by `bt it's not allow me to login`, Don't you just need to move to your home screen once you login as of response is sucess

Comment: yes I only need to move to my home screen but when I press the login button nothing is happen. don't you think m missing some code for what steps I have to perform after getting this token?.

Comment: You just need to push or present your home Screen on main thread that you want to show after login

Comment: let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate   appDelegate.gotoMainvc()     I'm using this but its working in any of the case whether I use this post request or not. can you tell me how to connect these two codes together ?

Comment: hey mate I followed this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756014/oauth2-0-token-access-request-with-password-grant-type-with-ios-swift-2-client  but m getting error of use of unresolved identifier 'KeychainWrapper'. will you please refer this answer let me know wht m missing.

Comment: That answer is uses KeychainWrapper custom library you can user `UserDefaults` instead of that

Comment: let saveToken:Bool = KeychainWrapper.setString(token, forKey: "access_token") have to replace this line with which code ?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866512/6433023 it is uses userdefault use that to store your value

Comment: hey mate have updated my question it would be great help of mine if you solve it.

Comment: Where you are getting this error

Comment: while debugging this error is comes at the task.resume() and after that debugger will come at the if data?.count != 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147267/discussion-between-silvervein-and-nirav-d).

Comment: @silvervein I believe the only problem with the above code is like you going into the mainVC no matter whether you have logged into the app or not right?

Comment: yes want to save the token in userfefaults and by using that saved token want to switch over to the home screen .

Comment: @silvervein I have added an answer please try it out and see if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hard coding the username and password in `bodyStr` update it to

```
self.bodyStr = "username=" + actualUsername + "&password=" + actualPassword + "&grant_type=password"
```

Update the statements inside `do` with

```
   do {

    let tokenDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    print(tokenDictionary)
                            // Get the token
    if let authToken = tokenDictionary["access_token"] as? String{
    self.token = authToken
    UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "access_token")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    } 
  }
```

You can implement a function like  isUserLoggedIn which will return true if token is saved in userDefaults. You need to check whether the user has logged in in the appDelegate's  `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.Like

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
if isUserLoggedIn(){
//showHomeViewController
} else{
//showLoginViewController
}
return true
}
   func isUserLoggedIn() -> Bool{
        if let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "access_token") as? String {
            if (accessToken.characters.count)! > 0{
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir your answer worked like a charm :) thanku thanku thanku very much.

Comment: That sounds great :)